# Server side validation for swagger

Tags: validation, yaml, swagger, rest

We have defined out REST APIs in Swagger definition for a website. The JS clients for these REST APIs are auto generated from the swagger model in YAML.

From a security perspective, we want to perform validations on the server side in our REST endpoints if the request conforms to the defined schema. is there any automated way in which this server side validation could be done using the same swagger model.

Comment: Swagger can not automatically generate validation on the server-side. You need to write the code.

Comment: https://openapi.tools/#data-validators